# Recursive asychrony is breaking my brain

Tags: c#, recursion, async-await, win-universal-app, iot

I am trying to write a simple Universal app that presents media files from a network / SAN.
I've managed to get the thing working end-to-end, I'm just having difficulty obtaining files from the network in a *reliable* way.

I have a feeling it is due to my poor grasp of asynchrony in C# and/or data binding in XAML apps, but I can't find a way through.

```
using Windows.Storage;

// Private field to keep files
private BlockingCollection<StorageFile> fileList = new BlockingCollection<StorageFile>();

// Called after page initialization
private async Task InitFilesAsync()
{
    var deviceRoot = KnownFolders.MediaServerDevices;
    await WalkFolderAsync(deviceRoot);
    foreach (var f in fileList)
    {
        this.lbxFiles.Items.Add(f);
    }
}
```

And the `WalkFolder` method looks like this:

```
private async Task WalkFolderAsync(StorageFolder parent)
{   
    var items = await parent.GetItemsAsync();
    foreach(var item in items)
    {
        if (item.IsOfType(StorageItemTypes.Folder))
        {
            await WalkFolderAsync((StorageFolder)item);
        }
        else if (item.IsOfType(StorageItemTypes.File))
        {
            fileList.Add((StorageFile)item);
        }
    }
}
```

Works ok to a degree; but sometimes 0 files come through, sometimes 5 or 6, and occasionally all fifteen files come through.

**Update:**
I have refactored my code slightly as per suggestions in the comments, but this has not improved anything.

**Update #2**
Still no luck really. It looks like the recursive async stuff (or indeed binding) may not be the problem; but possibly the device itself? I've tried handling any await call exceptions. I occasionally get Access Is Denied, but again this is not reproducible.

Comment: The main problem is likely that `List` is not thread safe and you're adding to it from multiple threads.  Either use a `lock` or a thread safe collection.  A second comment is you should be returning a `Task` from async methods else you have no ability to `await` them.

Comment: What would happen if WalkFolderAsync doesn't update the global fileList, but returns the list of items found?

Comment: Well originally I had tried writing the recursive method so that it accepted a `fileList` and returned the same list after additions took place. (since the `ref` keyword is not compatible with `async`).  Maybe trying this with a thread safe collection will work.  I shall give this a go.   Also, I'm starting to wonder about exceptions - my housemate connected their device to the network and then no files were coming through at all.  I eventually tracked this down to an `Access is Denied` exception...

Answer (score 3):

The root issue is your use of `async void`. You should **only** use `async void` for event handlers. Since they don't return a task you can `await` until completion they force unneeded multi-threading which your `List` doesn't support.

You also don't wait for the list to fill up before iterating it so you have a race condition.

You should make your `async` methods return `Task`s and `await` them which would make your "walk" asynchronous but sequential.

```
private async Task InitFilesAsync()
{
    await WalkFolderAsync(KnownFolders.MediaServerDevices);
    foreach (var f in fileList)
    {
        this.lbxFiles.Items.Add(f);
    }
}

private async Task WalkFolderAsync(StorageFolder parent)
{   
    var items = await parent.GetItemsAsync();
    foreach(var item in items)
    {
        if (item.IsOfType(StorageItemTypes.Folder))
        {
            await WalkFolderAsync((StorageFolder)item);
        }
        else if (item.IsOfType(StorageItemTypes.File))
        {
            fileList.Add((StorageFile)item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanations.  I have tried with the above code, and also using `BlockingCollection` instead of `List` for my file collection.  I am seeing nothing different really.  (I am invoking `InitFilesAsync` from the constructor, using `Task.Run(() => this.InitFilesAsync());` if that helps.  Does it matter where I instantiate my collection?

Comment: @ne1410s You don't need `Task.Run` when you call an `async` method. Also, you can't `await` in the constructor so you need to call it in the window load event.

Comment: I'd also avoid doing stuff in the window load event, because of [disappearing onload exceptions](http://blog.paulbetts.org/index.php/2010/07/20/the-case-of-the-disappearing-onload-exception-user-mode-callback-exceptions-in-x64/)

Comment: @ne1410s I can only guess that one of the calls to `WalkFolderAsync` isn't `await`ed in your code.

Comment: I have updated the question with the code changes suggested.  (I am still experiencing the same issues though).

Comment: @ne1410s If you call and `await` `InitFilesAsync` correctly this code should work.

Comment: @i3arnon +1 thanks for your help with this.  However I found that my media device was configured to implement CIFS, FTP, NFS and AFS simultaneously.  I disabled all except CIFS and it seems to be serving up folder and file info fine now. :oD   It also doesn't seem to *"like"* me firing requests at it rapidly; so I've implemented more of a folder-navigator control instead.